# How mempool works in Solana

Tags: transactions, network

Ethereum has a mempool which is a waiting area where unconfirmed transactions are put together. How does Solana handle those waiting transactions?

Answer (score 2):

Gulf Stream. Explainer post [here](https://medium.com/solana-labs/gulf-stream-solanas-mempool-less-transaction-forwarding-protocol-d342e72186ad).